# Build href call using form values

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple form like this:

```
<form action="emplist.html" method="post" rel="external">
Please enter one or several search items. Can be partial.
<label for="empid" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Employee ID:</label>
<input type="text" name="empid" id="s_empid" value="" placeholder="Employee ID"/>
<label for="lname" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Last Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="lname" id="s_lname" value="" placeholder="Last Name"/>
<label for="fname" class="ui-hidden-accessible">First Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="fname" id="s_fname" value="" placeholder="First Name"/>
<label for="department" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Department:</label>
<input type="text" name="department" id="s_department" value="" placeholder="Department"/>
<a href="emplist.html?eid=%s_empid&lnam=%s_lname&fnam=%s_fname&dep=%s_department" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="search" rel="external">Submit Search </a>
<input type="reset" value="Reset Form" data-theme="e" data-icon="delete"/>
```

Of course is not working as it is, but the general idea is to build the href URL with the form parameters I'm capturing.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: If you don't want to GET for some reason `$("form").serialize()` will give you an encoded query string.

Answer (score 2):

That's what [the GET method](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.3) is for. Use it in your form:

```
<form action="emplist.html" method="get" rel="external">
    <!-- all your fields should go here... -->
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Search" />
</form>
```

Comment: It seems to be working, somewhat, but I have a console alert in my GetUrlVars function, and the value of window.location.href shows the filesystem file, instead of the url. And no parameters. Which function to parse the parameters should I use?

Comment: @user1753599 - To get the query string, use `window.location.search`.

Comment: window.location.search is blank. Since I'm using cordova, I found that the url should be saved in $(this).data("url"), but still I'm getting undefined in the console.